# Counting days to a particular event

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the best choice when counting days to an event :

> 18 days left to New Year
>
> 18 days left till New Year
>
> 18 days left until New Year

Comment: Eighteen days till New Years? Eighteen days till New Years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year coming up is usually referred to as **the** new year.

> 18 days left **until** the new year.
>   18 days left **till** the new year.

Mean the same, the first is the best choice, the second sounds like a contraction *('til)* of the first sentence.

> 18 days left **to** the new year.

Would put you a year ahead of where you are **today**, though people would probably understand what you mean which is :

> 18 days left **in** the (current) year.

The informal ways to say this are :

> 18 days **left** until the new year
>   18 days **to go** until the new year
>   18 days **left to go** until the new year

Comment: But I don't think you'd capitalize "the new year" but you might capitalize '18 days 'til New Year's Eve" or "'til New Year's Day"

Comment: *Till* isn't a contraction.  It's the original word.

Comment: **Till** is an original word, but I have seen **'til** also used as a contraction for **until**, like **'em** in **go get** 'em(them)